# How to sort special price collection

Tags: magento-1.7, collection

I have a page with promotions based on set special price from/to date attribute and it shos fine. I have created a new attribute called flash that is a yes/no value. I want to order the previous collection so I show first the ones that have such attribute as a Yes. This is my code and it doesn't sort, the sql query doesn't have a order by clause. It doesn't work replacing setOrder with addAttributeToSort either.

```
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);

    $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', array('or'=> array(
            0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayDate),
            1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
        ), 'left')
        ->setOrder('flash', 'ASC')
        ->setPageSize($this->getProductsCount())
        ->setCurPage(1)

    ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on the query to fix this issue.

```
die((string)$collection->getSelect());
```

and check whether the ORDER BY clause is there. The code is correct from my perspective.

## Works

```
   $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);

    $collection->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
        ->addUrlRewrite()
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => now()))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', array('or'=> array(
                0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => now()),
                1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
                                                  ), 'left')
        ->addAttributeToSort('name')
        ->setPageSize(10)
        ->setCurPage(1)

    ;
    die((string)$collection->getSelect());
```

I have a `ORDER BY` clause. Did you refresh indexes and caches? I don't think this is the problem, but might be. I have no attribute flash here, so I just tried with name and this works.

Comment: My code does not have an order by clause (as I said on my question)

Comment: Sorry, I overread this part :-/ This doesn't make sense. I see no possibility neither in `setOrder` nor in `addAttributeToSort` to have NO `ORDER BY` clause. Edited the post.

Comment: You are right, when I have ->addAttributeToSort('name') I see the order by, if I change it to ->addAttributeToSort('flash') it's gone!

Comment: Make sure the attribute you are trying to sort by is in the addAttributeToSelect() 

If that does not work please make sure that you have set the property 'use in product listing' to "Yes" is of the flash attribute. 

If that doesn't work, well it just has to work :-P

Comment: there is no need for this. AddAttributeToSort handles the joins for itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code (Just to make sure that all previous order by's are removed):

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);

$collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
    ->addStoreFilter()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', array('or'=> array(0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayDate),1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))), 'left')
    ->setPageSize($this->getProductsCount())
    ->setCurPage(1)
;

$collection->clear()->getSelect()->reset('order');
$collection->getSelect()->order('flash ASC');
```

Let me know whether this works ;)

Comment: This seemed to break all my layout and the theme itself giving me an error: http://pastebin.com/ZDgpzYdA